# How to make cordova on Mac / iOS to stop adding a caret (^) in plugin version numbers in config.xml and package.json

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, package.json

I noticed that cordova (v8.1.2) when running on a Mac for iOS (v4.5.5) quite often adds a caret (^) before plugin version numbers.

This causes npm to silently update to the newest version of the same major version (e.g. 1.3.6 -> 1.4.2).

In the case of one of the plugins we use, this causes an issue, as there is a breaking change from 1.3 to 1.4, so I really like to stay with 1.3.

- Why does cordova do this?
- Is there any way to make cordova stop this?

It's a bit error-prone to always check both `config.xml` and `package.json` before checking in that there is no wrong version introduced.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the npm save prefix to empty

`npm config set save-prefix=''`